# Android Activity / TabActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

The Android app I am building uses a library that is constantly pushing data to a remote server. In a demo MyMainactivity did exactly this without any user interface and the activity worked well.
Now that I am building the UI around this activity with a TabView I am puzzled how to execute MyMainActivity - in my manifest I now have MyTabActivity as LAUNCHER so how can I make MyMainActivity and MyTabActivity both start up on launch? (MyMainActivity should run while the user is able to scroll through the tabs ans at a later stage should have influence on how MyMainActivity sends data to our servers).

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MyTabActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `MyMainActivity` in the first visible tab, so that it gets started when the tab is becoming visible.

Or you can launch `MyMainActivity` start what you need to do and then forward your app to the `MyTabActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Every activity with a GUI has an onCreate method that you override to define what happens when the activity is launched. You would add the code to run background service when MyTabActivity is created.

```
class MyTabActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyMainActivity.class);
       startService(myIntent);
    setContentView(viewid);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyTabActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

     <activity
        android:name=".MyMainactivity " >

    </activity>
   </activity>
```

Another way you also try by this way in your tab activity. Here, you use your stuff.

```
    <receiver android:name=".AutoConnection" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver



public class AutoConnection extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
```